# Finding value of 1 variable in a 3-variable $2^{nd}$ degree equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The question is: If $a,b,\space (a^2+b^2)/(ab-1)=q$ are positive integers, then prove that $q=5$. Also prove that for $q=5$ there are infinitely many solutions in $\mathbf N$ for $a$ and $b$. I simplified the equation as follows:-$$\frac {a^2+b^2}{ab-1}=q\\\begin{align}\\&=>\frac {2a^2+2b^2}{ab-1}=2q\\&=>\frac{a^2+b^2+2ab+a^2+b^2-2ab}{ab-1}=2q\\&=>(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2q(ab-1)\\&=>2(a+b)^2+2(a-b)^2=q(4ab-4)\\&=>2(a+b)^2+2(a-b)^2=q((a+b)^2-(a-b)^2-4)\end{align}$$Substituting $a+b=X$ and $a-b=Y$, we get $$2X^2+2Y^2=q(X^2-Y^2-4)\\\begin{align}&=>(q-2)X^2=(q+2)Y^2+4q\end{align}$$Now using the quadratic residues modulo $5$, I know that $X^2,Y^2\equiv0, \pm1(mod\space 5)$. But using this directly doesn't give the answer. So what to do after this? An answer without the use of co-ordinate geometry would be greatly appreciated as it seems there is a very good resemblance of the equation to a pair of hyperbolas which are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$ but I don't understand co-ordinate geometry very well.

Comment: i think you need the Vieta Jumping method

Comment: I have edited the question by adding the word positive in "positive integers". Can anyone prove now that $q=5$ and if that holds there are infinitely many solutions in natural numbers for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know that there exist infinite solutions, and are looking for the proof, or is it possible that there are finite solutions?

Comment: The question says that there are infinitely many solutions for $q=5$ and we have to prove that, so basically $\mathbf YES$, I know there are infinite solution and am looking for a proof..

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi not that you must must but it would be helpful if you accepted an answer.

Comment: @sciona, I would greatly love to accept an answer but none of the answers match the condition "without use of coordinate geometry". Yours and Han De Bruin's effort was really great so I have voted it up..

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi I see! thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer.** Sure I understand what the true question is about,
but I thought this would help. And it *has* helped because the
OP changed integers into "positive integers". In order to prevent a
bounty from being assigned automatically: don't upvote too much :-(

The equation can be rewritten as:
$$
F(a,b) = a^2+b^2 - q(ab-1) = 0
$$
If we now interpret $\,(a,b)\,$ as real valued coordinates,
then pictures can be made for the curve $\,F(a,b) = 0$ . Where $\color{green}{green}$ means $\,F(a,b)<0\,$ and $\color{red}{red}$ means $\,F(a,b)>0\,$ .
Two cases are distinguished: $\,q > 0\,$ and $\,q < 0$ ;
nowhere it has been said that the integers are positive.

Pictures of $\,F(a,b)=0\,$ for the case $\,q > 0$ , to be precise
$\,q=3$ , $q=5$ , $q=19$ :

[image]

The case $\,q=0\,$ is trivial: it follows that $\,x=y=0$ .
The case $\,q=1\,$ implies that there is no curve $\,F(a,b)=0$ :
$\,a^2+b^2-ab+1=(a-b)^2/2+(a^2+b^2)/2+1 > 0\,$ .
The case $\,q=2\,$ implies that there is no curve $\,F(a,b)=0$ :
$\,a^2+b^2-2ab+2=(a-b)^2+2 > 0\,$ .
The case $\,q=3\,$ is the first interesting case for $\,q > 0$ .
All curves for $\,q \ge 3\,$ are hyperbolas, because they have the form
of a conic section equation and the discriminant - similar to the one in
$\,Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0\,$ is : $\,B^2-4AC = q^2-4 > 0$ .

Pictures of $\,F(a,b)=0\,$ for the case $\,q < 0$ , to be precise
$\,q=-1$ , $q=-2$ , $q=-10$ :

[image]

The case $\,q=-1\,$ implies that the curve $\,F(a,b)=0\,$ is an *ellipse* :
$\,a^2+b^2+ab-1=0\,$ , namely a conic section with discriminant $= -3$ .
The case $\,q=-2\,$ implies that $\,F(a,b)=0\,$ is a degenenerate conic section:
$\,a^2+b^2+2ab-2=0$ $\Longrightarrow\;$ $a+b = \pm\sqrt{2}$ , i.e.
two parallel straight lines.
The hyperbolas are back in town with $\,q < -2$ .

About the integer solutions. Educated guess from the pictures:
$q=5 \;\Longrightarrow \;(a,b) = (2,1) \vee (1,2) \vee (-2,-1) \vee (-1,-2)$ .
$q=5 \;\Longrightarrow \;(a,b) = (3,1) \vee (1,3) \vee (-3,-1) \vee (-1,-3)$ .
$q=-1 \; \Longrightarrow \; (a,b) = (0,1) \vee (1,0) \vee (-1,0) \vee (0,-1)$ .

**Update.** The following Pascal program snippet indeed shows
that there are at least *many* solutions $\,(a,b)\,$ for $\,q=5$ :

```
program infinity;

Uses SysUtils;

function g(a,b : integer) : integer;
const
  q : integer = 5;
begin
  g := sqr(a)+sqr(b)-q*(a*b-1);
end;

function stop(x,y : integer) : boolean;
begin
  stop := (Length(IntToStr(x)) > 9)
       or (Length(IntToStr(y)) > 9);
end;

procedure crawler;
var
  x,y,f : integer;
begin
  x := 1; y := 1;
  while true do
  begin
    y := y + 1;
    f := g(x,y);
    if f = 0 then Writeln(x,' ',y);
    while f > 0 do
    begin
      x := x + 1;
      f := g(x,y);
      if f = 0 then Writeln(x,' ',y);
    end;
    if (f = 0) and stop(x,y) then Break;
  end;
end;

begin
  crawler;
end.
```

Output $\,a\;b$ , apart from the last (= overflow) record:

```
1 2
1 3
2 9
3 14
9 43
14 67
43 206
67 321
206 987
321 1538
987 4729
1538 7369
4729 22658
7369 35307
22658 108561
35307 169166
108561 520147
169166 810523
520147 2492174
810523 3883449
2492174 11940723
3883449 18606722
11940723 57211441
18606722 89150161
57211441 274116482
89150161 427144083
```

There is a lucid structure observed in the above sequence.
If the subsequent values of $\,a\,$ are numbered as $\,a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots\,$ and
if the subsequent values of $\,b\,$ are numbered as $\,b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots\,$ ,
then it seems that we have: $\,\forall n : a_{n+2} = b_n$ .
Let's solve some equations, to see where this may come from:
$$
a^2+b^2-5(ab-1) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
b = \frac{5a}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{21a^2-20}}{2}
$$
Now start with $\,a_1=a_2=1$ :
$$
b_1 = \frac{5}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21-20}}{2} = 2 \\
b_2 = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{21-20}}{2} = 3
$$
Giving the first two records in the output. However, the equation
$\,a^2+b^2-5(ab-1) = 0\,$ is *symmetric* in $\,(a,b)\,$ , so
the values of $\,b\,$ are at the same time new values of $\,a\,$ .
Thus we can proceed with $\,a_3=2\,$ and $\,a_4=3\,$ :
$$
\frac{5\cdot 2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21\cdot2^2-20}}{2} = 1 = a_1 \quad ; \quad
\frac{5\cdot 2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{21\cdot2^2-20}}{2} = 9 = b_3\\
\frac{5\cdot 3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21\cdot3^2-20}}{2} = 1 = a_2 \quad ; \quad
\frac{5\cdot 3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{21\cdot3^2-20}}{2} = 14 = b_4
$$
It becomes clear that the minus signs will reproduce old results. Hence,
recursively, starting with $\,(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)$ and $q=5$ : 
$$ 
a_{n} = b_{n-2} \quad ; \quad
b_{n} = \frac{5 a_n}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{21 a_n^2 - 20}}{2}
= q\,a_n-a_{n-2} = \frac{a_n^2+q}{a_{n-2}}
$$
That is for $\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\,$ with $\,n > 2$ .

Comment: you are to prove that $q=5$ in the only number which gives infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb N$ for a and b..and a solution without the use of co-ordinate geometry would be highly appreciated as stated in the question....

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi: Yes, I know. But that is beyond me at this moment. Hope you nevertheless appreciate the attempt. I'd suggest to treat it as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you have looked into the details of [Vieta Jumping wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping) link, so if we know the curve $x^2+y^2 - qxy + q = 0$ has a single integer solution then there are infinitely many, generated by the pair of iterations:

$$(x,y) \mapsto (qx-y,x)$$ $$(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$$

on the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2+-+5xy+%2B+5%3D+0&dataset=) of the curve.

Further observe that for a lattice point $(x,y)$ with $y > x >0$, the orbit of the iteration $(x,y) \mapsto (qx-y,x)$ does not change the branch of hyperbola, i.e., remains in the branch in the first quadrant.

Geometrically this is equivalent to moving from a lattice point $(x_0,y_0)$ to the point $(x_0,x_0)$ on the line $y = x$ and then join and extend the line joining $(x_0,x_0)$ and $(y_0,x_0)$ to meet the curve again at $(qx_0 - y_0,x_0)$.A sequence of iterations that will look like:

[image: *A rough diagram of the iteration around the vertex of the curve*]

Now, $x^2+y^2 - qxy + q = 0$ has no solution in natural numbers if $q = 1,2$

since,$x^2+y^2 - qxy + q > 0$ for $q = 1,2$.Thus, $q \ge 3$.

We note that the vertex of the branch in concern $\color{blue}{A} = \left(\sqrt{\frac{q}{q-2}},\sqrt{\frac{q}{q-2}}\right)$ lies on the line joining $\color{black}{J} = (1,1)$ and $\color{black}{H} = (2,2)$ for $q \ge 3$.

If $I = (x_i,y_i)$ is the lattice point in the orbit of the iteration closest to the vertex $\color{blue}{A}$, then the next point in the orbit $K$ no longer stays in the upper half (region $y>x$) part of the hyperbola, $K = (x_k,y_k)$ must lie in the lower half region ($x > y$).

But in order to go from $I$ to $K$ we find that the point on the line $x = y$, i.e., $(y_k,y_k)$ must be a lattice point as well. The only lattice point on this line between the origin and vertex $\color{blue}{A}$ is $J = (1,1)$, hence $y_k = 1$.

Therefore, both the roots of the quadratic $x^2+1 - qx + q = 0$ must be positive integers, viz $x_k$ and $qx_k - 1$.

The discriminant $\Delta = q^2 - 4(q+1)$ must be a perfect square. But $\Delta$ differs from $(q-2)^2$ by $8$, and the only perfect squares that differ by $8$ are $1$ & $9$.

$$\implies (q-2)^2 = 9 \implies  q = 5 \textrm{ since } q \ge 3$$

Comment: I'm stuck where it is argued that $(x,y)=(x,1)$ is a solution of $x^2+y^2-q(xy-1)=0$ . All I can see is that _if_ $(x,1)$ is a solution, _then_ it follows that $q=5$ .

Comment: @HandeBruijn Are you asking why the equation has a solution like $(x,1)$ ? or is it how I concluded from there $q = 5$?

Comment: Only the former part: can't follow where $(x,1)$ comes from.

Comment: @HandeBruijn The sequence of iterations starting from any lattice point on the curve gradually comes closer to the vertex $\color{blue}{A} = \left(\sqrt{\frac{q}{q-2}},\sqrt{\frac{q}{q-2}}\right)$. There can't be infinitely many points $(x,y)$ in the orbit with $y>x$, so at some point it must go to the $x>y$ part (demonstrated in the diagram with the points $I \to K$), but then the point $J$ on the $x = y$ line has the $x-$coordinate of $I$ and the $y$-coordinate of $K$(both integers), lies between $O=(0,0)$ and $\color{blue}{A}$.

Comment: @HandeBruijn But the only lattice point in the line joining $O$ and $A$ is $(1,1)$, so that must be it, $J = (1,1)$.

Comment: Ah, your iterations work the other way around, when compared
with mine: $b_{n-2} = a_n$ ; $a_{n-2} = q a_n - b_n$ . So yes,
I think you're right (+1).

Answer (score 1):

For such equations:

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-1}=-t^2$$

Using the solutions of the Pell equation.  $$p^2-(t^4-4)s^2=1$$

You can write the solution.

$$x=-4tps$$  $$y=t(p^2+2t^2ps+(t^4-4)s^2)$$

It all comes down to the Pell equation - as I said.  Considering specifically the equation:

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-1}=5$$

Decisions are determined such consistency.  Where the next value is determined using the previous one.

$$p_2=55p_1+252s_1$$  $$s_2=12p_1+55s_1$$

You start with numbers.  $(p_1;s_1) - (55 ; 12)$

Using these numbers, the solution can be written according to a formula.

$$y=p^2+2ps+21s^2$$  $$x=3p^2+26ps+63s^2$$

If you use an initial $(p_1 ; s_1) - (1 ; 1)$

Then the solutions are and are determined by formula.

$$y=s$$

$$x=\frac{p+5s}{2}$$

As the sequence it is possible to write endlessly. Then the solutions of the equation, too, can be infinite.

Comment: How does it help...and what exactly are $p$ and $s$? You have to prove that $-t^2$ in your solution is equal to 5 for integral solutions...

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi I said $p,s$ solving the Pell equation.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail...so that I can at least take a hint of how to prove q=5..

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi   This statement you want to prove wrong. What you need to prove? If there are other values of the ratio in which there are solutions.

Comment: Please look at the question again..

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi What should I with you to discuss?  You don't understand that the solution to such a binary quadratic form is defined by the solutions of the Pell equation.